# Qgis select distinct by default on Print Composer

Tags: qgis, sql, print-composer

I have a filter on Print Composer that selects "id_mov" and shows figures one by one into the map. This "id_mov" is not unique so different id can have the same "id_mov". 
Qgis select distinct by default and for the same "id_mov" I can't find the way to show them all together in the same map composition. It could be like saying in SQL "no select distinct"

Answer (score 1):

I studied your questions, because sometimes I need it..

My suggestion is depends of your format:

Case A: Shapefile
Create a new shapefile using "Dissolve" Tool

Case B: PostGIS:
Create a View using "Group by"

Comment: Dissolve seems clear but the view doesn't. How can I keep several figures with their own geometry in a single line? Group by results diferent id for every single geometry, am I right? Then I don't get the point for creating a view. Thnks ;)

Comment: You must to create a view like this exemple:create view my_view as 
  select st_union(the_geom) as the_geom, 
         sum(area_ha) as area_ha,
         id
  from my_table
  group by id

Comment: I didn't know st_union function. This works!!! Big Thnks!